# How to transform rrule date value from array to custom string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array like this:

```
     [{
evening_feeding: false
    evening_feeding_time: "19:00"
    feeding_frequency_rule: **"FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=2"**
    id: 890
    morning_feeding: true
    morning_feeding_time: "04:00"
    noon_feeding: false
    noon_feeding_time: "12:00"
    pen_id: 299
    start_feeding_date: "2020-07-07"
}]
```

I would like just to display this feeding_frequency_rule: **"FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=2"** as for example any string like **Every day** in my html view. Any suggestion for this?

Comment: Can you share your html, ts or what have you have tried so far? That way we can help you better. And the format seems a bit absurd to me. It is not properly formatted. Kindly share the code snippets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a function to format the rule, this would first parse the rule, then return a human readable string for the given rule.

If we can't find a match, we'll just return the raw FREQ value.

I've created a couple of rows of sample data, then displayed in a Bootstrap 4 table.

```js
let feedData = [
    { 
        evening_feeding: false, evening_feeding_time: "19:00", 
        feeding_frequency_rule: "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=2",
        id: 890, morning_feeding: true, morning_feeding_time: "04:00",
        noon_feeding: false, noon_feeding_time: "12:00",
        pen_id: 299, start_feeding_date: "2020-07-07"
    },
    { 
        evening_feeding: false, evening_feeding_time: "19:00", 
        feeding_frequency_rule: "FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=2",
        id: 891, morning_feeding: true, morning_feeding_time: "04:00",
        noon_feeding: false, noon_feeding_time: "12:00",
        pen_id: 300, start_feeding_date: "2020-07-07"
    }
]

function formatFeedingFrequencyRule(rule) { 
    let freq = rule.split(";")[0].split("=")[1].trim();
    switch (freq) {

        case "DAILY":
            return "Every day";

        case "WEEKLY":
            return "Every week";

        default:
            return freq;
    }
}

feedData.forEach(obj => { 
    document.getElementById("tbody_1").innerHTML += formatRow(obj);
});

function formatRow(obj) { 
    return `<tr><td>${obj.id}</td><td>${formatFeedingFrequencyRule(obj.feeding_frequency_rule)}</td>`
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <h5>Feeding Rules</h5>
  <table class="table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Feeding Frequency</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="tbody_1">
</tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
```